# URL Encoding : Javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion-2016

I have a javascript capturing signatures and data.
The " are getting lost/cutoff and not conserving.  I assume this is a URLEncoding issue.

This is the original.

```
     '<input type="hidden" name="rvnotes" value="' + rvnotes + '"/>' +
```

And I have tried this, but still no luck.  Any idea how to URL Encode the Javascript submission.

```
     '<input type="hidden" name="rvnotes" value="' + encodeURIComponent(rvnotes) + '"/>' +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick must be done in `<form>`.

```html
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ...>
```